# Determine darkest hex code from json response

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a json response that returns an object with different vehicles. Each product has a hexcode value as an attribute that related to the vehicle color:

```
[ { "name":"Ford", "hexCode": "4B1A1F"},
    { "name":"BMW", "hexCode": "FFFFFF"},
    { "name":"Fiat", "hexCode":"000000"}
]
```

What i would like to do is be able to determine from the hexcodes, which one would be the darkest color, since not all manufacturers will use #000000 for black.

Is this possible either through some sort or regex or JS?

Comment: How would the definition of dark be? For instance would #00ff00 be darker or brighter than say #0000ff? After which scale should the brightness bei measured?

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: convert the values to grey-scale and compare the values.. Best answer from Marcin Orlowski

Comment: @DevDig thats a good question. luckily each manufacturer is passing most available colors they produce to us so we should have a darkest grey or black.   We would not have to worry about your example about like a green or blue with the same luminosity.

Comment: @VladimirKovpak the only thing i tried was searching each manufacturer for the hex code of black in a simple JS for loop. That's how i discovered that not all use just plain black

Answer (score 2):

> since not all manufacturers will use #000000 for black.

Once you define what `darkest` really means for you things will get easier. The fact your source data is inaccurate does not help at first glance, yet it still should be possible to use it for your needs. As all you really care here is the the luminance, not the color itself, it should be worth a shot to [convert the value of provided color to gray-scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale) and then pick up the one closest to `0x00` as the darkest one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex if you are already using Javascript. Just assign the json to a variable and javascript will parse it, then convert each color to `HSL` and find the minimum by L value.

HSL is a color scheme that defines colors by Hue, Saturation, and Lightness, so you would get an objective measure of how 'dark' your color is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the luminance (Y) value for the RGB colors given in hex to find the lowest. The formula is;

```
Y = 0.299R + 0.587G + 0.114B
```

So you may do as follows;

```js
function getY(hexValue){
  return hexValue.match(/[0-9a-fA-F]{2}/g)
                 .map(h => parseInt("0x"+h))
                 .reduce((r,c,i) => (r[3] += r[i]*c, r),[0.299,0.587,0.114,0])[3];
}

var data = [ { "name":"Ford", "hexCode": "4B1A1F"},
             { "name":"BMW", "hexCode": "FFFFFF"},
             { "name":"Fiat", "hexCode":"000000"}
           ],
  result = data.map(d => Object.assign({},d, {Y: getY(d.hexCode)}))
               .reduce((p,c) => p.Y <= c.Y ? p : c);

console.log(result);
```